# Parameters not passing into an ActionResult

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

So I have this Javascript code:

```
function AddToStuff(somethingID) {
    var stuffID = document.getElementById('StuffID').innerText;

    alert("First Alert: " + stuffID);

    if (stuffID == -1) {
        document.getElementById('StuffID').innerText = 0;
        stuffID = 0;
    }

    alert("Second Alert: " + stuffID)
    StuffCallback.fire(somethingID, stuffID);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeStuff();
});

var StuffCallback = $.Callbacks();

function initializeStuff() {
    StuffCallback.add(function (somethingID, stuffID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "pos/Stuff",
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                somethingID: somethingID,
                stuffID: stuffID
            },

            success: function (result, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert("Third Alert: " + stuffID);
                var contentArea = $("#Stuff");

                contentArea.html(result);
                $("#Stuff").hide();
                $("#Stuff").show({ duration: 250 });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this C# code:

```
public ActionResult Stuff(int somethingID = 0, int stuffID = -1)
    {               
            if (stuffID == -1)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (stuffID == 0)
            {
               //do something else
            }
            else
            {
                //do something else
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the C# method always has stuffID at -1 and so performs the first "if" case.

When the page loads and $(document).ready calls initializeStuff, the stuffID is -1, so it performs the first "if" case, as desired.  Later, when AddToStuff() is called, because the user clicked on something, it reads in my element StuffID, which I have initialized to -1.  The First Alert does display the -1.  Then StuffID gets changed to 0 in the "if" inside AddToStuff() and the Second Alert does display the 0.

But then I have the Javascript function AddToStuff call the C# function again, but the goal is to have the second parameter (stuffID) be the 0 instead of the -1.  And even the Third Alert will display a 0.  But in the C# function, the stuffID is still -1.

I can't pass in the 0.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I generalized my code into "something" and "stuff", but that part should be working fine - the functions call when I expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use fiddler or developer tools in your browser to see what is being passed to the server (0, or -1)?
- The default value to `Stuff(int somethingID = 0, int stuffID = -1)` can also be causing the problem if the data received by the server is not correct.
- Set the data type in your Ajax call `dataType: 'json'`
- If you are using a `GET` request, make sure that you have set the `data` object correctly

Comment: Changing the data type in the Ajax call worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I comment all your JS code and just write

```
 StuffCallback.fire(0, 5);
```

it works nicely, as it accepts 5. That means that your stuffID is not being recognized as int. What kind of a HTML element is it? I see you are using .innerText. As you are using jQuery already, why not use

```
var stuffID = $('#StuffID').val();
```

I have noticed your problem though. You have a typo.
getElementById('StuffID') and your p is called "stuffID". JS IS case sensitive, so it will be enough to fix that, but please use

```
<input type="hidden" ID="StuffID" value="@stuffID">
```

as that's proper HTML markup

Comment: stuffID's element is as follows:<p id="stuffID" style="display:none;">@stuffID</p>, so it's a paragraph.

Comment: that's wrong. Change it to <input type="hidden" value="@stuffID" /> as that's what input hidden is for. And then use my $('#StuffID').val() and check it out then

Comment: input type="hidden" needs ID which will be exactly the same (case wise too) as ID you are calling in JS.

Comment: I now have <input type="hidden" ID="StuffID" value="@stuffID" /> for the element and function AddToStuff(somethingID) {
        var stuffID = $('#StuffID').val();
        alert("First AddToStuff: " + stuffID);

        if (stuffID == -1) {
            document.getElementById('StuffID').innerText = 0;
            stuffID = 0;
        }

        alert("Second AddToStuff: " + stuffID);
    
        StuffCallback.fire(somethingID, stuffID);}  Alerts show "-1" and "0", but the C# function is still always -1.

Comment: If you change <input type="hidden" ID="StuffID" value="@stuffID" /> to <input type="hidden" ID="StuffID" value="3" /> what happens?
If it is 3 then you have a problem with @stuffID

Comment: <input type="hidden" ID="StuffID" value="3" /> results in -1 still being passed in, though 3 is displayed in the alerts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123555/discussion-between-user3402743-and-zoran-p).